# Why changing .htaccess file in Elastic Beanstalk tomcat environment is not reflected?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .htaccess, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have java 8 tomcat application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk on AWS. My initial design was that blog (WordPress) would be on same server as tomcat. But since this is Elastic Beanstalk, I moved by blog to a different EC2 (a different IP address). The blog works after I set up subdomain in Route53 as `blog.syz.com`. But I want to divert the traffic from `xyz.com/blog` to `blog.xyz.com`.

I am doing this by modifying `.htaccess` file.

I added a `.htaccess` file in the root of tomcat application and deployed to Elastic Beanstalk. But the redirect is not working.

To test, I tried changing the path of existing and do a redirect using `.htaccess`, but does not seem to take affect. Re started server but still not working.

What am I missing here?

Do I have to configure using `.ebextension` in Elastic Beanstalk?

Normally `.htaccess` in root folder should work.

Comment: `.htaccess` are Apache config files, not Tomcat?

Comment: EBS does comes with apache 2.4 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-platform.html. So maybe I am modifying in incorrect location?

Comment: The document you link to contains further links to [include your own (Apache) `.conf` files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-tomcat-proxy.html) - these would be server-side config files. Maybe you can implement your redirect here? (But note that the syntax may be different in a server context, as opposed to a directory/.htaccess context.) Oridinarily, Apache 2.4 does not enable the use of `.htaccess` files by default and you must explicitly set `AllowOverridde All` in the server config to enable this. (Maybe this is the same with EBS?)